# Using CheckCapabilities of Server Object Extension?

Tags: arcgis-server, server-object-extension

I am testing a [sample project](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/0001/000100000pq2000000.htm)  for SOE.

The constructor of this sample SOE is :

```
public NetSimpleRESTSOEWithCapabilities()
        {
            soeName = this.GetType().Name;
            reqHandler = new SoeRestImpl(soeName, CreateRestSchema(), CheckCapabilities) as IRESTRequestHandler;
        }
```

and the CheckCapabilities method:

```
private bool CheckCapabilities(string configCapabilities, string requiredCapability,
          object resourceOrOperation, NameValueCollection boundVariables, JsonObject operInput, string requestProperties)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requiredCapability))
                return true;
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(configCapabilities))
                    return false;
            }

            string caps = configCapabilities.ToLowerInvariant();

            HashSet<string> configCaps = new HashSet<string>(caps.Split(','));
            if (!configCaps.Contains(requiredCapability))
                return false;

            return true;
        }
```

I need to know what does this method do exactly?

I couldn't find any resources in ArcObjects documents.